# How to sort in pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

Current code is showing results in random order but I want to display  USA list first in order to India, UK and China.

```
@obj = User.where(:area => ["USA","India","UK","China"]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 1)
```

I am using Paginate gem.

```
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `sql` trick to order by a predefined list.

```
@obj = User.where(area: %w(USA India UK China))
  .order("area = 'USA' desc")
  .order("area = 'India' desc")
  .order("area = 'UK' desc")
  .order("area = 'China' desc")
  .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 1)
```

Comment: Tq @Iceman, your working good when i am changing (area: %w(USA India UK, China) to (:area => ['USA', 'India', 'UK', 'China')), tq very much

Comment: `%w()` works too, it's just syntactic sugar to create a string array

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you need by adding a simple CASE logic to your ordering, try this:

```
@collection = User
  .where(area: %w(USA India UK China))
  .order("CASE area WHEN 'USA' THEN 'a' WHEN 'India' THEN 'b' WHEN 'UK' THEN 'c' ELSE 'd' END")
  .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 1)
```

Given CASE syntax could vary according your RDBMS, you should check if you need to adjust something. Hope it helps.

Comment: To the person that kindly down vote my answer, I'd like to know why is not useful.